# Web-based UI element for selecting a geographical location

Tags: google-maps, user-interface, mapping, geolocation

I'd like to create / use a UI element for a web-site that provides a world map, on which the user can draw a circle to indicate an area of interest. I'd like information on the coordinates of the area covered by the circle to be available to me via Javascript for sending back to the server over Ajax.

Does such a control exist, and if not how difficult would this be to implement using something like Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google would have that as part of it's api as would OpenLayers

Answer (score 1):

maybe Artem GoogleMap can help you.